# How to move ListView up/down after adding via builder

Tags: flutter

When adding an item with builder and "itemBuilder:...", how do you automatically scroll to the top or button - depending "reverse".

Following gives an error with no description:

```
return ListView.builder(
                  reverse: true,
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: list.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(list[index]),
                    );
                  },
                ).controller.animateTo(0.5, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are calling an `animateTo` method at the end, this return statement will not return a widget. I assume you are assigning this snippet as a Widget or as a child, and it will give you an error.

For fixing it I can suggest something like this.

```
           // Assign your ListView to a variable and return that variable.
           ListView list = ListView.builder(
              reverse: true,
              controller: _scrollController,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: list.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(list[index]),
                );
              },
            );

            //Animate it afterward. Preferably inside a button or listener.
            list.controller.animateTo(0.5, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100), curve: null);
```